# Storing variable

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way in postgresql to store the value of a particular column into a variable.

Eg.

```
name   | age
       |
John   | 19
Phill  | 20
Palmer | 25
```

I would like to store 25 into a variable I can reference in the future.

Comment: describe the whole picture. It's not clear what you're trying to archive.

Comment: I want to store 25 into a variable I can reuse. For example age= 25. age * 2 = 50

Comment: yep, stored procedures ) i've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use stored procedures. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html
Trivial example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JohnName()
      RETURNS numeric AS
    $BODY$
      DECLARE num numeric;
      BEGIN
        select age into num from yourtable where name = 'John';
        num := num * 2;
        RETURN num;
      END
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

      select * from JohnName()
```

Comment: Well, I am looking for something such as     let palmAge = Select age from Students where name = 'palmer'